# Can I merge two different angular version projects?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, json-server

I followed an angular e-commerece project on youtube I wanted to merge it with angular login project that require me to install json-server, when I typed
`npm install json-server`

I got this error

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/animations@15.2.7
> npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@15.2.9
> npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
> npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^15.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@
> 14.1.1                                                                                                      npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
> npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^14.1.1" from the root project
> npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^15.2.9" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"15.2.7" from @angular/animations@15.2.7
> npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
> npm ERR!   peerOptional @angular/animations@"15.2.7" from @angular/platf
> orm-browser@15.2.7                                                                                          npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
> npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"15.2.7" from @angular/forms
> @15.2.7                                                                                                     npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
> npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@"^15.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-boots
> trap@14.1.1                                                                                                 npm ERR!       node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
> npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
> npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router,
> the root project)                                                                                          npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^15.2.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@15.2.7
> npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
> npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"15.2.7" from @angular/animations@15.2.7
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
> npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"15.2.7" from @angular/pla
> tform-browser@15.2.7                                                                                        npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
> npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"15.2.7" from @angular/for
> ms@15.2.7                                                                                                   npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
> npm ERR!         peer @angular/forms@"^15.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-boo
> tstrap@14.1.1                                                                                               npm ERR!         node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
> npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
> npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/route
> r, the root project)                                                                                        npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^15.2.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency reso
> lution.                                                                                                     npm ERR!
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! For a full report see:
> npm ERR! C:\Users\amm25\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-05-12T12_20_3
> 1_412Z-eresolve-report.txt
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\amm25\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-05-12T12_20_31_412Z-debug-0.log
> PS C:\Windows\System32\AngularArabicProject

`

I searched for number of solutions until I found this solution

`npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`

It worked for me the json-server is installed successfully but whenever I try to run "ng serve" I got this error

> Build at: 2023-05-13T23:22:02.191Z - Hash: 5f214f4e7e2b0adf - Time: 43629ms
> ./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
> Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.
> ./node_modules/@angular/localize/fesm2020/init.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Windows\System32\AngularArabicProject.angular\cache\15.2.6\babel-webpack\77833be5e6924f778051ec71be4ca66ad6435e7eb6a70fb905428c2beb76e757.json'
> Error: Can't resolve 'node-modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css' in 'C:\Windows\System32\AngularArabicProject'
> Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - NGCC failed.
> *Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ *
> × Failed to compile.

Can anybody help?
I am working on my graduation project and I have to merge two angular projects to be able to deliver one big project, if anyone can solve the issue or can give me a suggestion I would be happy :)